# Strip_tags PHP MySQL not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having trouble getting this to work I want to make sure that if the user adds HTML tags or PHP tags in the text fields in a form that they do not get added into the database.
The code that I have now adds the strip_tags along with the HTML and PHP tags into the database.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
      //Check for Valid Email
function valid_email($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}


    //Add people Information to Database 
function addToDB ($sql, $con) {
require 'db.php';

    $sql= ("INSERT INTO people (name,email) VALUES(
            'strip_tags($_POST[name])', 
           '($_POST[email])')");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_close($con);
}

    //Add vehicle Information to Database
function addToDB1 ($sql, $con) {
require 'db.php';

$sql="INSERT INTO vehicle (year, make, model, color)
VALUES
('$_POST[year]','$_POST[make]', '$_POST[model]', '$_POST[color]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: I will add that I only have it the function added to the first entry I havent gotten around to adding it to the rest....

Comment: your code is wide open to sql injection attacks

Comment: Ive been searching google and I just found a post saying the same thing about SQL injection it says I should use mysqli prepared statements instead so I might look into that

Comment: You cannot call functions from inside a string. Make it `'".strip_tags($_POST[name])."'`, and yes escape your values before appending them to your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not possible to call functions within a string as you do for displaying variables on double quoted strings!**

So your query needs to be something like that :

```
$sql= 'INSERT INTO people (name,email) VALUES(\''.strip_tags($_POST[name]).'\', \''.$_POST[email].'\')';
```

by the way, you should really consider to escape your input data coming from post/get variables! Something like:

```
$sql= 'INSERT INTO people (name,email) VALUES(\''.mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST[name])).'\', \''.$_POST[email].'\')';
```

The best alternative, however, would be to use prepared statements to prevent sql injection!

---

Eidt : if you are working with variables within strings use {$_POST[email]} and not ($_POST[email]) to mantain your varnames consistent!

Comment: Anyone reading this, mysql_real_escape_string has been deprecated, an alternative is mysqli_real_escape_string